# mkdir(): Permission denied error in php docker nginx

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Im getting mkdir(): Permission denied error in dockerised php.

I need to create folder dynamically inside /app ,

tried with `mkdir('/app/images/' 0777, true)`

chown for particular folder is `www-data:www-data`

Please see the excerpt from docker composer file

```
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: PHP.Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
            - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
```

Comment: www-data normally is the Apache2 default user. Try php-fpm instead.

Comment: Unless your PHP is running as root or the owner of the parent directory, you may not be able to set permissions. Also the permission value is affected by the current umask. Check documentation for details.